# Strange type empty Flow syntax inside default statement of Redux reducer

Tags: redux, flowtype

I found the code sample while searching for ways to use flow with redux here:
https://flow.org/en/docs/frameworks/redux/

Peculiar syntax is (action: empty); Is it just a bit of flow magic intended to be used just inside default case of switch statement or does it have other uses?

It looks like out of place function type statement without return value type but with parameter of strange type 'empty', which I couldn't find documentation about.

```
// @flow
type State = { +value: boolean };

type FooAction = { type: "FOO", foo: boolean };
type BarAction = { type: "BAR", bar: boolean };

type Action = FooAction | BarAction;

function reducer(state: State, action: Action): State {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "FOO": return { ...state, value: action.foo };
    case "BAR": return { ...state, value: action.bar };
    default:
      (action: empty);
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`empty` is Flow's [bottom type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom_type). I believe the main motivation for its initial introduction was symmetry but it has proven to have some uses. As you have identified it can be used in this case to make Flow enforce exhaustiveness. It can be used similarly in a chain of `if`/`else` statements.

However, it can be used anytime when you want Flow to prevent any actual value from ending up somewhere. This is very vague, so here are a couple examples:

```
// Error: empty is incompatble with implicitly-returned undefined
function foo(): empty {
}

// No error since the function return is not reached
function foo2(): empty {
  throw new Error('');
}

function bar(x: empty): void {
}

// Error: too few arguments
bar();
// Error: undefined is incompatible with empty
bar(undefined);
```

In the `foo` examples, we can see that Flow enforces that a `return` is never reached in a function returning `empty`. In the `bar` example, we can see that Flow prevents the function from being called.

Comment: Good explanation of empty, thank you, is there a url where I can read more about it? Also, would be nice to find out more about syntax of (action: empty); - it is not return type nor does it look like function parameter type. Does babel transpiles it somehow?

Comment: If it's documented somewhere, I'm not aware of it. This syntax is just a type assertion. You can put any expression on the left and any type on the right.

Comment: AFAIK it's the only way to define the type for an object with no keys. `type emptyObj = { [string]: empty }`